# Dynamic column name in Cursor PLSQL-Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamicquery

I am working on a query in pl/sql. I've almost same named columns like **column1, column2, column3**.

In Cursor, how can i get value of these columns using dynamically name.

My query:

```
FOR Cursor_r IN Cursor_c LOOP
    BEGIN 

        IF Cursor_r.column1 = 'dummy1' THEN 
             MyProc(Cursor_r.column1);
        ELSIF Cursor_r.column1 = 'dummy2' THEN
             MyProc(Cursor_r.column2);
        ELSIF Cursor_r.column1 = 'dummy3' THEN
             MyProc(Cursor_r.column3);
        END IF;

    END; 
END LOOP;
```

I need any dynamically structure solution for these columns.

It won't work but FOR EXAMPLE like this or another solution:

`Cursor_r.column||1
 Cursor_r.column||2`

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have defined cursor_c somewhere. so you know what the columns are.

Comment: Take a look at the DBMS_SQL package from oracle.

Comment: @Rene i edited my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  You could do this instead:

```
FOR Cursor_r IN Cursor_c LOOP
    BEGIN 
        MyProc
            ( CASE Cursor_r.column1
                  WHEN 'dummy1' THEN Cursor_r.column1
                  WHEN 'dummy2' THEN Cursor_r.column2
                  WHEN 'dummy3' THEN Cursor_r.column3
                  END
             );
    END; 
END LOOP;
```